# Unique Data Uplload in Python Excel

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

In New API(Python-Odo o) I Successfully upload Excel File.

But if second time i upload same file Data are Duplicated.
So How I upload only Unique Data.

If No Change in Excel file no changes in recored

But if Change in Data 
this only recored updated reaming recored same as upload.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For that you need atleast one field to identify the record to check the duplicacy.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello viral,**

When you upload first time data in excel that time take one unique column(i.e ID)
and when you second time upload data that time check the unique column, **if** `found so only update their data` **else** `upload data as new record`.